# Консумация и консуммация

Tags: орфография, семантика

В разных источниках встречается написания **консуммация** и **консумация**.
Есть даже версия, косвенно подтверждаемая википедией и вики-словарем, что это два разных слова.

Но вот в чем беда: ни в одном источнике я не нашел в явном виде оба слова.
В обычных словарях - только "консумация", "консуммация" есть, правда, в википедии, но там нет "консумации". В вики-словаре - наоборот, только "консумация".

Есть ли авторитетный источник, который помог бы разобраться?
(+)===
По поводу двух разных слов. Согласно этой версии:

**Консуммация** (от латинского consumation - подтверждение) в средневековой традиции - завершающая часть брачного ритуала, вступление в супружеские отношения.
**Консумация** (от латинского consumo — "потребляю") - услуга в ночных барах и стрип-клубах, общение девушки с посетителем, "оплатой" которого являются чаевые и/или заказ для дамы напитков.

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем там вторая М.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой "Зачем" - это не тот вопрос. Откуда - понятно. От латинского *consummation* - подтверждение.

Comment: Ой, а я вообще подумал о потреблении — consumption по-английски. Простите!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  - так вот и полагают, что это разные слова. Хотя... английский вариант давал бы "консумпция". да и пос смыслу он как-то не очень. Я добавлю в текст.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - а с "потреблением" вы были правы. Нашел я. Только не от английского, а от опят же латинского ***consumo*** - потребляю.